# Can't Change HTML dropdown select option background on hover on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background color for HTML select option tag when hover over it.
But unfortunately, cant do that on Chrome Browser. Though it works on Microsoft Edge

**Chrome Version:**
*Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

**HTML Code Snippet**

```
<select class="gender-dropdown">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Gender</option>
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
    <option value="3">Transgender</option>
    <option value="4">Other</option>
</select>
```

**CSS Code Snippet**

```
select:focus option:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Weirdly, when i use `<select class="gender-dropdown" onfocus="this.size=5">` this works with same CSS, but i want to use it without onfocus function. I have found similar problems with solutions but none of them worked for me. May be because most of them are quite old.

Am I missing something here? Any Help/Guidance is appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

**Working Code Snippet**
https://www.codeply.com/p/HShzArOdic

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to styling the select option, there are limited options.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

If you want full control over styling the options you would need to do your own custom implementation, or use one from a library.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of the recent Chrome update. See this link to fix the issue.

**[Select options black border after chrome upgrade](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48974735?hl=en)**

Answer (score 0):

That black border is a new feature for form controls in Chrome version 83.

You can disable this in your Chrome, accessing [chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh](http://chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh)
and disabling the Web Platform Controls updated UI flag.

[image]